# Laravel dom crawler search img in javascript

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I have part of html content:

```
$("table:first").after("<a href=\"https://example.com/test123/\" style=\"display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 116px;\"><img src=\"https://example.com/images/banners/image.png\" alt=\"Example\" width=\"88px\"  style=\"display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; \"></a>");
```

I need search `img` and `attr` `src` with value `https://example.com/images/banners/image.png`.

I do:

```
    $html = $content ? new Crawler($content) : [];

    $res = false;

    foreach ($html->filter('img')->previousAll() as $element) {
        if (in_array($element->attr('src'), [asset('images/banners/image.png')])) {
            $res = true;
        } else {
            $res = false;
        }
    }
```

But I get `false`. Why? If `img` is not inside in jQuery, then everything is working. But if `img` is in jquery then how can I get `true`?

Comment: Could you put a log statement in your `foreach` to see if the image was even picked up? I'm guessing JQuery might not have added the image by the time you run the `foreach` loop above.

Comment: @DelenaMalan yep you right. I don't get image on page. How I can set timeout?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is [symfony/dom-crawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) the package that you're using?

Comment: @DelenaMalan Yep. You right

Comment: @DelenaMalan I use guzzle/http for get html from other site. I use Dom Crawler symphony with guzzle.

Comment: grammar, formatting, bad syntax

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [symfony/dom-crawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) package doesn't support Javascript. It only loads static html and xml documents, and doesn't load and render Javascript like a browser would. It looks like [fabpot/goutte](https://packagist.org/packages/fabpot/goutte) or [symfony/panther](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/panther) are packages that you can use together with dom-crawler to crawl sites where you want the Javascript to be loaded and run. They use BrowserKit in the background which simulates a browser.

Comment: But can I check with regular expression if image exists?

Comment: If you use the above mentioned packages, yes. If you only use the dom-crawler package, no. Assume that the page's Javascript (and thus the JQuery) wouldn't be run at all if you only use dom-crawler.

Comment: This answer would be more useful with sample code tailored to the question.

Comment: @DelenaMalan I get content of html with guzzle/http. How I can check on image exists with regular expression?

Comment: Do you mean content that was added by JQuery or the content that is in the document before JQuery added anything?